# When a fragment is active?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, fragmentmanager

We have an android app that uses fragments. Everything works fine but, there is a crash that rarely happens and which I haven't been able to reproduce.
The error says:

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException Unable to start activity
> ComponentInfo{.../...Activity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
> Fragment already active
>
> android.support.v4.app.Fragment.setArguments (Fragment.java:551)

The code I have on the line that crashes is:

```
Fragment fragment;
try {
    fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
} catch(IllegalAccessException ex) {
        fragment = null;
} catch(InstantiationException ex) {
        fragment = null;
}
if(fragment != null) {
    if(args != null)    fragment.setArguments(args);
    final FragmentTransaction ft = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(mFrameLayoutResource, fragment, fragmentTAG);
    ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
}
```

As you can see, the crash happens on setArguments, but I haven't been able to reproduce it, and I even don't understand what is wrong with my code. When a fragment is active? And how can I know if my fragment is active before setting the arguments, in order to avoid that crash?

The issue is ought to android's fragment code:

```
public void setArguments(Bundle args) {
    if (mIndex >= 0) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Fragment already active");
    }
    mArguments = args;
}
```

But I don't understand why mIndex is greater or equal to 0 in my case... Do you have any idea about what is going on here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: as documentation state, you can only use setArguments before first use of the fragment in transaction ...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The fragment is new, so it shouldn't be a problem :( I've edited my question with the line where the fragment is created

Comment: i can't belive ... it is almost not possible ... why you have null check before `fragment` usage if you are using `fragmentClass.newInstance()`(please, fix your naming convetion - use upper case as first letter and remove Class from class name) right before?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The code I wrote was a simplification of my real code, the fragmentClass.newInstance() requires a try-catch, and thats why the null check is required. I've edited the code with that try-catch.

Comment: `fragmentClass` is object of `Class<?>` class? or it is a class name? (`fragmentClass.newInstance()` is your static method or `Class<?>.newInstance()`?)

Comment: fragmentClass is object of Class (Class fragmentClass), and newInstance() is the android's native method

Comment: I give up ... I see only possibility: one of the fragment class adds itself to the transaction in the constructor.